# Video Streaming in android Using Java server

Tags: java, javascript, android, web-services, plugins

I have an android application by which i need to upload video from IP Camera to a server and have to stream that from another device from that server. That is I have to stream live video from Ip Camera using java .

I have the android application. But I don't know how to write the server part.Is there any javascript pulgins to accomplish that? Anyone please help.
Thanks in advance.